# .map function returning duplicate element angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I get an array through a PHP backend, which shows like below :

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "code":"0000",
      "message":"OK"
   },
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "description":"Description 1",
         "image":"work\/(1)(1).jpg",
         "job_id":"5",
         "final_upload":"N"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "description":"Description 2",
         "image":"work.jpg",
         "job_id":"5",
         "final_upload":"Y"
      }
   ]
}
```

On my page i have an ng-repeat list of user ID's , I need to map the user ID to the job_id element in the array that i receive above. So that the image and description related to that job_id will show.

As shown above , there's 2 job_id elements with value "5".

I receive the array above by resolving it as workList.

With the following function i pass in the user_id and map it to the workList array and attempt to retrieve the image and descriptions related to that ID.

```
$scope.viewWork = function(id) {
                var uid = id;
                $scope.works = workList.map(item =>
                    ({
                        image: workList.find(work => work.job_id === uid).image,
                        description: workList.find(work => work.job_id === uid).description,
                    }));
            }
```

The ID posts fine , and then I have an ng-repeat element to display the results...

```
<tr ng-repeat="works in works">

<td>{{ works.image }}</td>
<td>{{ works.description }}</td>

</tr>
```

But what i receive is always only the first matching element. The second result is a duplicate of the first. But I do receive 2 results , which is what it should be, But the issue is both of them are the same and not showing the actual second result..

I'm trying to get both matching image and description values for the job_id == 5, But it only returns the first matching element twice....

Thanks for any help .

Comment: Try filtering before your map function instead of inside it... I don't know if that will make a difference, but it is definitely more optimized. `worklist.filter((el) => el.job_id === uid).map((item) => ... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that inside `map` you are looking for the job_id with `find` which matches the first result, therefore pushing the same result (the first one) twice to the resulting array, because there are two elements in the original array.

Take a look at the code below. It might shed some light.

```js
var workList = [  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "description":"Description 1",
         "image":"work\/(1)(1).jpg",
         "job_id":"5",
         "final_upload":"N"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "description":"Description 2",
         "image":"work.jpg",
         "job_id":"5",
         "final_upload":"Y"
      }
   ];

var viewWork = function(id) {
  var uid = id;
  return workList.map(item => (item.job_id == id ? {
    image: item.image,
    description: item.description,
  } : null));
}

console.log(viewWork(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking the item up twice.

1. `map`
2. `find` inside `map` (which searches on the full list again every time)

You can simply `filter` -> `map` the output to match what you are looking, and return it in the appropriate format. Or you can do a one pass map with a conditional like @JorgeObregon has posted you.

```
$scope.works = workList
  .filter(item => item.job_id === id)
  .map(item => { image: item.image, description: item.description });
```